# Real-time developer notifications

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-pubsub

I have successfully configured google's real time notification for IAP. But for more than a month I have not received any notification about my end point (a user has purchased IAP). So where is the problem??
[real time notify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvDEU.png)

I clicked send test notification and it was successful. But the notification for real purchases was not sent to my end point.
[test success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXQX4.png)